# vue-multiselect single select with tag option

Tags: vue-multiselect

Anyone knows if it is possible to set vue-multiselect component with a prop :multiple="false" and still have a selection appear as a tag.

I have tried adding tag slot but it is not working.

Searching this all over the net and can't make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please try :max=1

You can always refer to the API:
https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-props